# Icon overlays are showing blurry on "Large Icons"

Tags: icons, overlay, windows-shell

We use Icon Overlays to show a state to the users. All but one of our icons are shown sharp.

This unsharpness only happens when we set the explorer to the large icon view.

We can't figure out why this happens.
We tried different tools to create th icon file.

This is the result :

[image]

And we started from this image:

[image]

You can find the source files (png's) and the ico file [here](http://nmd.sk/JL3ZbO4X)

Does anyone knows how to fix this or what is causing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973841/how-does-the-windows-shell-resize-icon-overlays/22994570#22994570

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I have all these sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a specific of Windows resize engine.

In large icons mode shell uses 48x48x32 icon. I created icon with grid:

[image]

And shell draws this icon without any interpolation:

[image]

And it looks like there is no solution of your problem.

Comment: Thx for the help, it looks like we'll have to rethink our icons then.